# Turn off the lead assignment email notifications

Tags: apex

How to turn off the lead assignment email notification ??

In my case,We don't have any Assignment rules ,lead owner is changed through apex trigger ,We don't want users to receive these Lead Assignment notifications .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to another that I answered, you might find it useful: [Case Assignment Notification Suppression](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/446/case-assignment-notification-suppression/450#450)

SF Documentation on the EmailHeader option: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm#emailheader

The relevant part:

```
//THIS DMLOPTION SEEMS TO BE IGNORED IN BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGERS
Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dlo.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = false;
dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = false;
dlo.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail = false;

database.update(casesList,dlo);
```

Comment: I had already tried setting the DMLOptions but no use.Lead assignment emails are still getting generated.

Answer (score 2):

There is some workaround would be to create a Queue, assign the user to that - and then uncheck the "email members of queue" in the Queue setup.  Then assign those leads to that Queue rather than the user directly. By using this method, you can turnoff email notification for specific user as well.

Comment: I have around 500 users i wonder its not the better sollution creating the 500 queues.