# How to stop New Lead alert to queue?

Tags: queue, notification

We have an 'Orphan Leads' Queue, which once a user is deactivated, we move all his open leads to that queue.
I don't have the setting to send alert to the members
[image]

But when I change the owner ship (I use workbench) each queue member gets the 'A new lead has been assigned to you'.

How can I stop the alert from being sent?
Should I use a different method to change the owner?

Answer (score 0):

Email notification is expected if the Queue is not assigned a Queue Email. Check [Stop email notification to queue members](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323036&type=1&mode=1) for more details.  Also there is a [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IXfuQAG) around email notification if the assignment of records are done through Flow/Process.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[I guess this is related](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/turn-off-the-lead-assignment-email-notifications)

The only option is to disable email alert in lead settings and implement email alerts for the required queues by workflows or other methods