# Send email to lead owner on assignement

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I have created an cutom lead capture form. I am searching for existing lead or account. If lead or account exists it should get assigned to exhisting lead owner.
I am assigning the lead owner through code.

```
    dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true; 

if(ownerId==null)
{
    leadToCreate.setOptions(dmo);   
}
else
{
    leadToCreate.OwnerId=ownerId;   
}
database.insert(leadToCreate, dmo);
```

Here owner gets assigned but after that it is assigned to lead assignment rule.

To avoid assignement rule the I have set

```
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= false;

`if(ownerId==null)
{
    leadToCreate.setOptions(dmo);   
}
else
{
    leadToCreate.OwnerId=ownerId;  
    dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= false; 
}
database.insert(leadToCreate, dmo);`
```

But problem here is i am not able to get email notification on lead assignement.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003781&language=en_US

Comment: check this hope this will helpful http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/446/case-assignment-notification-suppression/450#450